# JTextArea.append() taking a few seconds

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextarea

I know this is a dumb question, but I'm not sure what I can do. 
My program is to simply send a message through some servers. My program also has a "console", which is just a JTextArea, to let the user know what's going on. For some weird reason, calling the append() method takes a few seconds. In fact, it doesn't actually append until the message has been sent through the servers. That's where I'm lost. At the same time I append, I also use System.out.println() to log, and the log is printed instantly in the console, whereas appending the JTextArea does not. The only reason I came up with was that maybe the gui thread is different than an action thread. I send this message at a click of a JButton:

```
submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                console.append("Sending POST to GCM\n");
                System.out.println((String) textField.getSelectedItem());

                String apiKey = "...";
                Content content;

                try {
                    content = createContent("test");
                    POST2GCM.post(apiKey, content);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
```

As you see, I append, then log. My log shows up instantly, but the append() doesn't show up until the POST2GCM.post(apiKey, content) method has ran.

Can someone explain why this is, and if there is any workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yours is a Swing threading issue. All server communication should be done on a background thread, and all JTextArea text updates should be done on the Swing event thread. Use a SwingWorker, especially its publish/process method pairs to update your JTextArea (would a JList be better?), and your code should work a lot better.

Comment: Just to clarify it: your update to the JTextArea was done as fast as always, but your UI component won't be repainted until your method is complete.